# Can I make Beautiful Soup keep the attributes ordering and lines indentation

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am using Bueatiful Soup with the XML parser

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/root/sandbox/garbage/example_jmx.jmx"), "xml")
```

This keeps the attributes upper\lower case as in the parsed file. (FYI, Using the "lxml" parser results in all the attributes being saved as lower case.)

But I am left with 2 other problems.

1. The order of the attributes is changed.
2. The indentation of the lines is lost. All the lines are aligned to the right

e.g.for #1

```
<TestPlan enabled="true" guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan">
```

turns to

```
<TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" enabled="true">
```

How can I keep the original attributes order and lines indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the bs4 store tag's attribute in `dict` object, `dict` is unordered object.
2. indentation do not matter in bs4, it uses `children` `parent` to show the relationship of tag.

If you want to keep all the indentation and order of attribute, you should open the file directly.

Comment: Thanks. bs4 has such nice parsing capabilities, but the lack of these 2 features makes it unusable for editing JMeter's files and tracking the changes in tools like GIT. Saving from bs4 and then  opening and saving from JMeter, jumbles up every line.

Comment: For editing applications, general-purpose parsers are usually unsuitable. Apart from the issue of maintaining trivial lexical detail in the source, there's also the question of how to handle ill-formed input text - you don't want to switch off all syntax highlighting just because there's an error somewhere near the end of the document, for example.